# C Code generated from Mathematica not working?

Tags: code-generation, c-codegenerator

I am a .Net developer. I'm trying to build a Visual C++ application using C code generated from Mathematica (by another person). I don't have Mathematica installed on my machine. When I try to compile my code, I get this error:

> "Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WolframLibraryData_new referenced in function _wmain"

Can anyone help me with this? Do I need to have Mathematica installed on my machine in order to use C code compiled from Mathematica?
Or are there some .h/.dll/.lib files that I should be including in my project?
Any help would be appreciated.

[This](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Introduction.html) is a link to the Mathematica documentation which says this can be done:

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "WolframRTL.h"
#include "funct.h"

static WolframLibraryData libData=0;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    mint version=2;
    libData = WolframLibraryData_new(version); //error is at this line
    Initialize_funct(libData);

    double A1[10][10]={{258.3379872132036,178.815628898537,274.5474024360497,674.9391898068819,223.178274172278,880.9581284722401,132.54033649875424,791.5414955768498,928.458244854092,853.042661440361},
    {326.39463864136036,65.54849946988038,7.013535695540694,760.8886179075255,892.4870852590801,154.85960584875158,993.9999549781506,376.1879698639858,852.6107989941474,643.4517088040595},
    {182.6857552274334,183.10740080449298,115.54339508284843,739.9140368208969,924.3477680142298,4.291771905955958,840.9959926467988,64.97484701401486,701.1694938419519,123.33364343371585},
    {708.4556561480445,273.433351437165,772.7112489878598,270.29098199335476,382.06101750668415,207.88485196728465,765.6977132923191,509.4023640858293,489.57393224760403,53.02524611853305},
    {771.6977583141684,133.21439422184343,636.9631332534566,409.5735373144735,589.012003086735,950.1069934173505,521.4197381706082,669.6595004935767,664.6642350725052,945.8152215113945},
    {680.4237455238093,604.6846534795618,963.4947412305534,822.4815780776786,971.9680893757649,331.25130204239684,190.78349224269357,552.1905960843238,589.9070718690806,123.36645007511217},
    {425.08577895037445,42.78823199849459,100.33313962147668,70.34120395657912,653.3880206362061,909.5738377766511,463.37000636802014,660.7676666421056,64.37601754947093,959.4668443593006},
    {941.9502681974119,991.1081661485289,399.7117824769657,13.651622847906154,261.5265226736025,386.4235126689671,436.2170412464123,191.17004477022746,289.5584332978377,55.17221062657027},
    {245.43354900371878,638.9794486859037,699.651361428757,931.8057605514581,820.3477700533443,596.191216687409,599.3182218072803,861.464556594879,166.9597494171383,686.6173789107579},
    {135.94821543926025,200.69688995277338,102.58373186766738,727.1505345514572,193.9979472418483,209.58872380424447,702.8719493907016,713.498911703551,932.4714245682458,823.1652111352774}};

    MTensor B1;
    mint type = MType_Real;
    mint dims[2];
    mint rank = 2;
    int err;
    dims[0] = 10;
    dims[1] = 10;
    err = libData->MTensor_new( type, rank, dims, &B1); 

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            err = libData->MTensor_setReal(B1, dims, A1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    MTensor result;
    err = libData->MTensor_new(type, rank, dims, &result);  

    int A2=2;

    funct(libData, B1, A2, &result); //this is the function compiled from Mathematica

    double *res[10] ;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        res[i]= (*(libData->MTensor_getRealData))(&result[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to that page my answer was wrong, so I deleted it.  Please include a link to that page in your question!

Comment: I haven't attempted this, but I would imagine that at least you are going to need the mathematica libraries that implement the function calls you are trying to make.

Comment: I have tried adding all possible .lib, .dll and .h files as explained here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/CodeGeneration.html#139183296, but still getting the same error. Anyone have any suggestions? If you need any more info, please post a comment.

Comment: You need to link the `libWolframRTL` during your compiling stage. I can create an executable from a slightly modified version of your source with [this commandline](http://pastebin.com/7W2H0HvJ). Remember that you don't need everything there, but you need to specify the position of the library and you need to tell `-lWolframRTL`. This can be different on Windows since I'm on Linux here!

Comment: Tried it, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: By the way, I'm using a trial version of Mathematica for this purpose. (I need to evaluate Mathematica interaction with .Net before I decide to purchase the full version.) Could this be the reason why this code is not working?